# How to draw the results of a previous function into a new function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

New Code:

```
var totalEval = function (attendanceAverage, assignmentAverage, quizAverage) {

        return (quizAverage * .25 + assignmentAverage * .65 + attendanceAverage * .1 );
    },
    courseGrade = function (percent) {
      if (percent >= .90 ){return "A";}
        else if(percent >= .80){return "B";}
        else if(percent >= .70){return "C";}
        else if(percent >= .60){return "D";}
        else {return "F";}
};
```

Call:

```
var projectedGrade = courseGrade(totalEval(attendanceAverage, assignmentAverage, quizAverage));

window.document.getElementById('currentGrade').innerHTML = projectedGrade;
```

Now it's not calling it correctly; I get no result at all.

Edit: After much talking about it and demonstrating the following code, here's my question in a nutshell: How do I take the numerical value in totalEval and use it to create the letter grade in courseGrade?

Edit: New code, still doing the same thing, but now drawing on the function that holds the numberical score I'm trying to work with. Still giving everyone F's:

```
var courseGrade = function(totalEval){

  if (totalEval >= .90 ){return "A";}
  else if(totalEval >= .80){return "B";}
  else if(totalEval >= .70){return "C";}
  else if(totalEval >= .60){return "D";}
  else {return "F";}
};
```

Easy question, I'm very sure, but I can't seem to get it. For a simple program to take a numerical score and translate it into a letter grade, I have the following:

```
    var courseGrade = function(percent){
      if (percent >= .90 ){return "A";}
      else if(percent >= .80){return "B";}
      else if(percent >= .70){return "C";}
      else if(percent >= .60){return "D";}
      else {return "F";}
    };
```

The issue is, how do I draw the previously determined result into this function? To clarify, if the function I've used to collect all assignment/test/etc grades into one total average is called "totalAverage", how does one take totalAverage and input whatever the result is inside this given function?

The code creating the totalSum from which I'm drawing the numerical score to become the letter grade, noting the weighted aspect of each element of the total:

```
var totalEval=function(attendanceAverage, assignmentAverage, quizAverage){

var totalSum = (quizAverage*.25 + assignmentAverage*.65 + attendanceAverage*.1 );


return totalSum;

};
```

Comment: Like this? `var avg = totalAverage();  var grade = courseGrade(avg);`.  Or even like this?  `var grade = courseGrade(totalAverage())`.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I don't believe so, not exactly, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying - which is always a possibility for me!

Can I insert any of those variables into this function? I don't know why this is tripping me up.

Comment: You see, right now it's automatically giving the student an F every time, regardless of actual score.

Comment: How are you calling this `courseGrade` function?  What are you passing it?

Comment: If you can't call `courseGrade()` from a function which defines `totalAverage`, the answer depends on the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Scope_and_the_function_stack) you execute the functions. You can use a variable declared in the same scope (or outer) as both of these functions (if they are within the same scope or share an outer scope). The "last resort" is to use the global scope.

Comment: Rocket Hazmat, is this what you're asking? This is how it's being passed into the html, via a larger function:

var projectedGrade = courseGrade();

window.document.getElementById('currentGrade').innerHTML = projectedGrade;

Comment: @user3697742: Ok.  That's what I was asking, yes.  Now, where do you get the `totalAverage`?

Comment: @user3697742: Ok.  So, what's the problem here?  Do you want `totalEval()` to return a letter or a number?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski How would you advise transferring percent into score? I intended courseGrade for that purpose, or so I believed.

Comment: I want totalEval to return a number, but then take that number and assign it a letter grade via another function.

Comment: Where do you set `courseGrade`?  Maybe it's in the wrong scope?

Comment: Teemu, totalAverage is actually totalSum within my code, I mistyped it. I edited the initial post to include the code that creates totalSum.

Beyond where I use it to insert the score into the html, what I've shown you is the only instance of courseGrade.

Comment: Ack, I realized that totalEval is what we should be considering, not totalSum! Again, I apologize. I wrote this code at a horrible hour last night...

Comment: I summarized what I believe the actual question is, after speaking with you all about it, at the beginning of the original question. I hope it helps.

Comment: If you have these functions within the same [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope), I can't see anything, which would prevent you to use the third snippet in the Rocket's very first comment in this thread, just use correct function name in the argument. This way `percent` in `courseGrade()` will be equal to `totalSum`.

Comment: And that's the tricky part, and what's frustrating me. It's still not working. I changed it to the correct variable, and the function continues to give every score an F. It seems to be ignoring the rest of the function and skipping straight to the end. I tried removing the last part of the function, it becomes undefined upon testing.

Comment: When I tried the indicated snippet, it broke the code. :(

Comment: Can you use `console.log` (it's a debugging tool, press ctrl+shift+j to view) to print out `percent`. So, in the function `courseGrade`, what does `console.log(percent)` give?

Comment: I replaced percent with totalEval, since that's the number I'm trying to draw from. I did try percent, just in case, but it's as I thought - Undefined. Using console.log() on totalEval, of course, brought up its creation. I do appreciate the suggestion, I'm familiar with console.log(), but the person who usually advises me isn't fond of its use, so I frequently forget it as an option. I'll post what I have now in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've a script like this:

```
var totalEval = function (attendanceAverage, assignmentAverage, quizAverage) {
        return (quizAverage * .25 + assignmentAverage * .65 + attendanceAverage * .1 );
    },
    courseGrade = function (percent) {
      if (percent >= .90 ){return "A";}
                ...
    },
    ...;
```

Then, when you need to get a "courseGrade", you'll call the function calculating it like this:

```
var cG = courseGrade(totalEval(attendanceAverage, assignmentAverage, quizAverage));
```

In this function call, `totalEval()` is executed first, then the value it returns is passed to `courseGrade()`, and in that function `percentage` gets the value returned from `totalEval()`.

Notice, that in the arguments of the function call of `totalEval` you need to use actual values, or alternatively names of some variables holding the values corresponding "`attendanceAverage`" etc.

In your question you have changed the name of the argument within the initiatation of the `courseGrade()`. The name of the argument in the initiatation is not important, arguments are getting their values when the function is *invoked*.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, and it makes total sense, but for some reason it's still not working; now I get no result at all, not even the previously obtained persistent "F". I'm looking it over, seeing if I can catch the error, but I wanted to let you know, perhaps you have some insight. I posted the updated code at the top of the original post.

Comment: @user3697742 I've created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r78A7/) for you. Please study the fiddle and read carefully the [MDN page about Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions). If this won't help you to achieve what you want, I'll give up, good luck with this : ).

Comment: Thank you! :) Is there anything else I need to do to close this thread? I want to make sure I do this thing according to protocol. :)

Comment: @user3697742 If you feel you can solve your problem using my answer, you can accept it. When a question has an accepted answer, other users can see that your problem is solved (and we both get some rep).